# Twitter Bootstrap 3 navbar

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap in my website. When I'm trying to make a navbar, I cannot see the collapse button. Here's my code:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" id="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="btn btn-default navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="collapse">
                  <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                  <span class="gryphicon gryphicon-align-justify"></span>
               </a>
               <a class="navbar-brand" href="/index" id="brand">eTalk</a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="navi">
                    <li><a href="/index">Etusivu</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It works fine in my laptop, but when I view it in my tablet it looks like this:
https://imageshack.com/i/pdef92a1j

And in my phone it looks like this:
https://imageshack.com/i/pc43413aj

The navigation links disappear. How can I make the collapse button visible?

I've included Bootstrap CSS, JavaScript and latest jQuery.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I just copy the navbar code from bootstrap website http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/

Comment: @Rodrigo thanks, it's now working. I'm wondering what made the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem was in the following line of code:

```
<span class="gryphicon gryphicon-align-justify"></span>
```

Which should be:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></span>
```

### **[Demo JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dXspL/4/)**

Comment: Missing an "l" in the 2nd "glyphicon" in your 2nd code snippet

Answer (score 0):

The example from the website + your things.

`data-target` for the toggle link was different than the `id` of the `.collapse` element (collapse != navbar-collapse)
Now it is just the default `bs-example-navbar-collapse-1`

In bootstrap pay attention at the class names and the correct hierarchies. Always check their docs first.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify">Toggle</span>
            </a>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/index">eTalk</a>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="navi">
                <li><a href="/index">Etusivu</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```